# Defining private class in .cpp while mentioning it in .h

Tags: c++, stl, functor, private-members

**.h**

```
class MonotonePieces
{
    ...
private:
    class CompEdges;
    set<int, CompEdges> _edgesCrossingLine;
};
```

**.cpp**

```
class MonotonePieces::CompEdges
{
    ...
};

MonotonePieces::MonotonePieces(const vector<Vector2>& vertices) : 
    _edgesCrossingLine((CompEdges(_vertices, &this->_sweepingLinePosition))),
{}
```

With this i get error:

> 'MonotonePieces::CompEdges' : an undefined class is not allowed as an
>   argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_empty'

Class usage is:

```
MonotonePieces mp(poly);
```

Comment: Better come up with another solution other then std::set, or you might use pointer to implementation idiom to move std::set to cpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition `std::set<int, CompEdges> _edgesCrossingLine` needs to know the size of `CompEdges` to be complete.  So you must define `CompEdges` prior to this line.  However, you are still free to place the implementation of `CompEdges`'s methods in the .cpp file.